# Shell Scripting: How to read the response of adb devices and store it

Tags: android, linux, shell

I am trying to make a small shell script that would pass some adb commands, reboot the device, and once the device reboots, again pass some adb commands.
I was thinking of passing adb devices at regular intervals through out the period the device is rebooting so as to know when the next adb command could be passed(not sure there are any other better methods for doing this). For this purpose I need to check the response of each adb devices command. Is there any method to read this response?
I am a novice in shell scripts. Kindly excuse it the method I am adopting to achieve this task is not correct. 
Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an if statement from the response:

```
device=$(adb devices) 
while true 
do 
sleep 5 
if [ "$(adb devices)"="$device" ];
    then
    echo "device rebooted"
    break
  fi
done
```

This would check ten times in an intervall of 5 secs.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It had worked. I just modified it like below:

Comment: Cool, I'll change my answer for other people searching for this. Did you have it like so?